# Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcodebuild

[image]

my Xcode is  Version 4.4.1

The project worked perfect before updating to this newer version, but now it stopped working

Comment: Estimation is new xcode with old not compatible

Comment: Ok, not sure if this is the Problem in Your Project. But what fixed it for me, was to change the Name of the Info.plist File. 

 1. I changed the name from Info.plist to my-project-info.plist
 2. also change it under target-build-settings/Packaging/Info.plist
 3. Than delete the App from Devices/Simulators and re-run the App through Xcode

In my Case, everything worked fine since than. In my Case **there was nothing wrong with the specifications made in the plist file or with the valid architectures**.

Comment: My Solution Find Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20798054/1092219

Comment: It's a compiler issue, you can set the 'Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C' flag under build options to default or Apple LLVM 5.0.

Comment: Target -> Build Settings -> Build Options set the "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" - "Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.0)" and the issue will be solved

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have had the same issue when making multiple targets. My issue was that I had to change my Product Name under Packaging.

In each target project > Build Settings > Packaging -> Product Name

Comment: this fixed it for me, opening an old project on my Mac

Comment: Had same problem on my project. Build settings-> Complier for C/C++/Objective c was set wrong. I changed it to default compiler available, it worked!!

Comment: Just rename Product Name with the same name,and it worked~

Comment: @iphonegeek thanks. Build settings-> Complier for C/C++/Objective c when changed to default compiler available, solved my problem.

Comment: @KiranS you should make an answer with this comment.

Comment: @khaledannajar: not sure how ? seems the question is closed

Comment: @KiranS You are right I did not notice that. :)

Answer (score 27):

I wanted to install my old application on iPad. I updated the my XCode from 4.3.2 to XCode 4.5 and having this problem.I tried searched alot finally got this solution.

In your **target** settings (not project settings), please check the following settings there

> Valid Architectures : armv7

In my case, there was arm6 which i removed from it and it works.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you lose by removing the arm6? Surely you are sacrificing compatibility or something?

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue today.
If you have added any file check if you didn't also add info.plist with the files. Remove that and it will work.

Comment: Please note that Info files may exist under one of your "Library Search Paths" directories. and not necessarily added to your project files! (took me hours to notice)

Answer (score 3):

In your  Info.plist remove a string "Required device capabilities armv7"

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error message thrown at me today.

I was working in a workspace with a few iOS App projects and a Framework project (using https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework). I had just added that Framework project and tested things out in the iPhone emulator, but when I went to just fire up any of the apps on my iPhone, they all threw this error (mentionned above).

Turns out I fixed the problem by just removing the Framework project from the workspace. I could use the framework from within an iOS app without trouble, but the framework project could live in the same workspace for some reason.

Hope this helps anyone in my situation!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue I had added the Info.plist from the Facebook SDK 3.5 to my Xcode project.  As soon as I removed the facebook Into.plist file everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

In your Info.plist remove a string "Required device capabilities opengles-1"