# Xcode cannot run using the selected device. error No supported iOS device

Tags: iphone

I am trying to test my application on iPhone device it gives the error.But it works in simulator. Is there any problem in build settings?   ..

[image]

Comment: have u install the provisioning profile. it is much needed to run the app in real device. and that device's uuid must be added to that profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode cannot run using the selected device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257944/xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround

1. If the minimum compile target Version is set higher than the current Target Version,
2. If the Valid Architectures in the Build Settings is set incorrectly, the above error may occur.
3. Fixed by setting Compiler for C / C ++ / Objective-C Default compile (Apple LLVM 5.0) in Build Options